# Errors using PHP CLI with MAMP: module APIs don't match

Tags: php, pdo, command-line-interface

MAMP 3.05 out of the box gave me PHP 5.5.10 and PHP CLI 5.4.24. I'm running on Mac OSX 10.9.3.

PHP runs great when I enter a url in the browser, but the CLI gives me errors like this in the logfile:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdo_mysql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20121212
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

So my PDO stuff won't work. It doesn't report any failures in the logfile; my call to `new PDO` just causes the script to terminate silently. `php -m` shows that PDO is there. In the logfile there are other warnings about other modules, with the same problem: "These options need to match".

Other answers to questions like this don't give me much to go on; some of them say that PHP needs to be recompiled. But I didn't compile PHP--it came with MAMP. Does the PHP CLI just not work properly with an out-of-the-box install of MAMP? Is there some non-rebuild way to get this to work, or do I just have to rebuild it?

Comment: There is also XAMP, maybe a bit more powerfull and dev oriented ..

Comment: Why are you mixing PHP and PHP CLI versions? If you do need to have two version of PHP, make sure the web server is not using the CLI version, and that the CLI version is not using the web server version extensions.

Comment: @Reuben I'm not mixing the versions, at least not deliberately. This is out-of-the-box MAMP.

Comment: Do you know about the second php.ini file for CLI, you should double check the module is installed

Comment: That's terribly confusing of them to allow the product to be configured with one PHP version for web, and one PHP version for CLI. I understand if they supply two versions of PHP, but only running one at a time, and switching both web server and CLI at the same time would be the norm. You may need to try their PHP version switch program, and make sure only PHP 5.5.10 is running, for web server and for CLI. When you switch PHP versions, be sure to restart any terminal sessions, so the path gets updated.

Comment: @meda Yeah, I pointed the CLI to the ini for my normal config. Thanks.

Comment: ok so try upggrading because It sounds like something is not compatible.  upgrade php and its modules. hope this helps @GreatBigBore